# Computer software with symbolic representation of differential operator

Tags: metric-tensor, computational-physics, differentiation, software

I wrote a matlab code for curl, divergence, gradient, and laplacian as shown below. By changing the value of $h1,h2,h3$, I was able to obtain the Symbolic Representation of result in the different coordinate system, i.e. the one for cylinder coordinate was shown below.

However, I met a problem: the matlab did not assume communitive/ cancellation rule in several cases. 
For example, $Vx*(Vy*x+Vz)$ was not the same as $Vx*(Vy*x^2+Vz*x)/x$.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Or is there any other software could give me the satisfied result?

I know that there were several software capable to give numerical calculation, but not all of them could give the symbolic calculation like matlab. Right now its only 3 by 3 metric, but if we goes into 4*4 tensor, it's almost impossible to calculate by hand in a fair amount of time.

syms x y z p;

syms Vx(x,y,z) Vy(x,y,z) Vz(x,y,z);

A=[  Vx(x,y,z) Vy(x,y,z) Vz(x,y,z)  ];

%cylinder

h1=1;

h2=x;

h3=1;

syms S(x,y,z);

B=[S(x,y,z)];

%cross product

cucurl=@(A) 1/(h1*h2*h3)*[h1* (diff( h3*A(3),y) - diff( h2*A(2),z) ), - h2* (diff( h3*A(3),x) - diff( h1*A(1),z) )   ,  h3* (diff( h2*A(2),x) - diff( h1*A(1),y) ) ];

%Gradient use for scalar only

cugra=@(S)  1* [(1/h1*diff(S,x)) , (1/h2 *diff(S,y))   ,  (1/h3*diff(S,z)) ];

%Divergence

cudiv=@(A)  1/(h1*h2*h3)*  [ diff( A(1)*h2*h3, x )+ diff(A(2)*h1*h3, y )  + diff(A(3)*h2*h1, z ) ];

%Laplacian

culap=@(S)  cudiv( cugra(S));
pretty( subs(culap(B)))
 pretty( subs(cugra(B)))
 pretty( subs(cudiv(A)))
 pretty( subs(cucurl(A)))

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or even on the original https://stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: Have you tried Mathematica, which is usually more amenable to analytic derivations?

Comment: Maxima is AFAIK the best general-purpose open-source computer algebra system.

Comment: Link to Maxima's page: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/

I find the wxMaxima gui of it pretty handy. https://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/

Comment: You're basically looking for a [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system), of which there are [a variety of proprietary & freeware implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python sympy package, Mathematica and SageMath.
With sympy package use $init_printing()$ to obtain handwriting style output.